# .apk file generation from android-studio in ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio, apk

I have tried many of the times to generate .apk file from android-studio for my new application. and I am using android-studio in ubuntu. How to generate .apk file from android studio in ubuntu...? Not signed apk file.please help me..

advance Thanks

Comment: Just run your code using studio.If your configurations are right you will get .apk

Comment: Thank you ajit pratap singh.could you tell me the configuration settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to run your project and after that go to < your project location >/app/build/outputs/apk folder. There you will see app-debug.apk file.

Comment: Thank you salim.i will try and tell you